# How to get the time difference in minutes in python for time expressed in this format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time, python-datetime

I am using Python 2.7. I want to find the time difference in minutes with the variables below;

```
import datetime  
#Time Format (YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS)
TimeStart = '2014-06-30 13:23:46'
TimeEnd = datetime.datetime.now()
```

I want to write a function that returns the time difference in minutes using a floating data type. If the time difference is 90secs, then the function returns 1.5. This is the function I wrote but unfortunately, it is far from working.

```
def getTimeDifferenceFromNow(TimeStart, TimeEnd):
    timeDiff = TimeEnd - TimeStart
    return divmod(timeDiff.days * 86400 + timeDiff.seconds, 60)
```

How can this be done in Python 2.7? Forget about the function I wrote if it is too far from the right answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to *parse* your input string before you can do this:

```
TimeStart = datetime.datetime.strptime(TimeStart, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I'd do this *before* calling `getTimeDifferenceFromNow()`.

Once you subtracted two `datetime` objects, the `timedelta` produced has a handy method called [`timedelta.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds); divide that by 60 to get the delta in minutes instead:

```
def getTimeDifferenceFromNow(TimeStart, TimeEnd):
    timeDiff = TimeEnd - TimeStart
    return timeDiff.total_seconds() / 60
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> TimeStart = datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 30, 13, 23, 46)
>>> TimeEnd = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> TimeEnd
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 1, 11, 31, 59, 134990)
>>> def getTimeDifferenceFromNow(TimeStart, TimeEnd):
...     timeDiff = TimeEnd - TimeStart
...     return timeDiff.total_seconds() / 60
... 
>>> getTimeDifferenceFromNow(TimeStart, TimeEnd)
1328.2189165000002
```